# The name 'matches' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace RegexTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "The quick brown fox.";
            string pat = "fox";
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Match matches = rgx.Match(str);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles and runs without errors.
I have a breakpoint set at `Console.ReadKey()`, because I wanted to inspect the variable matches.
But I got the strange error message I put in the title of this thread.
The web wasn't clear about what it meant.

Comment: You can also print the value of `matches` like: `if (matches.Success)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(matches.Value);
 }`

Answer (score 6):

If you have switchen on `Optimize Code` then the variable `matches` is optimized away. This is generally the case if your current build profile is  `RELEASE`. Change it to `DEBUG` then no code optimization is used and you can access the desired variables.

Answer (score 1):

This variable is not used so it was optimized away. Add something like this, as a temporary solution:

```
int x = matches.GetHashCode();
```

Alternatively you can turn off optimizations temporarily, or compile in Debug mode.

Comment: This is going out of scope, I believe.

Comment: @HarveySpecter The breakpoint is at `Console.ReadKey` so it's in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can uncheck the Optimized Code option in solution properties.

```
Solution Properties > Build > Optimized Code
```

[image]

Comment: I wouln't do that, neither suggest it to do it, for your current shown configuration which is `Release`.

Comment: @xxMUROxx I suggested work around with Release Mode On